# The called constructor method for WP_Widget is deprecated since version 4.3.0 File Location

Tags: wordpress, deprecated

I apologize in advance for the rookie question. I just realize a site I created years ago is broken after it automatically updated to Wordpress 4.9 and I get this error. I tried enabling Debug and I get all the error messages but after reading many similar questions and some answers, I still can't find where should I edit to change

$this->WP_Widget(
to
parent::__construct(

So I can deal with the plugins giving these errors. If you can point me with more detail where is the file I need to edit? So far, options.php has nothing related to any of those words.

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress changed how constructors are handled since 4.3.0, to use the standard __construct() method. So the constructor of the widget definition should be:

```
class My_Widget extends WP_Widget {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct(
        'my-widget', // Base ID
        'My Widget', // Name
        array( 'description' =&amp;gt; 'My Widget description.' ) // Args
    );
}

function widget($args, $instance) {
```

See this article for more details: [Fixing “The called constructor method for WP_Widget is deprecated since version 4.3.0!” error on WordPress](https://techblog.hostmoz.net/en/fixing-the-called-constructor-method-for-wp_widget-is-deprecated-since-version-4-3-0-error-on-wordpress/)